# CSRF Fix not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, security, csrf, lightning-web-security

Below is a dummy LWC component to update a Custom Object record field (Year__c) value.

## Dummylwc.html

```
  <template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="ANTI-CSRF TEST COMPONENT"></lightning-modal-header>
      <lightning-modal-body>
          <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
              <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustObject_XXX__c" record-id='0a2XXXXXXXXX' >
               <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                   <div class="slds-col">
                     <lightning-input-field field-name="Year__c"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={handleSave} type="submit" label="Submit"></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>

</lightning-modal-body>
```

## Dummylwc.js

```
  import { wire, track } from 'lwc';
  import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
  import getRecord from '@salesforce/apex/Function.getTestRecord';


  export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {

      @track yr='';

      @wire(getRecord)
      getRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
          this.yr = data[0].Year__c;
        }
      } 

    handleSave() {
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
    }

}
```

## DummyLWC.cls

```
  public with sharing Class Function{

      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
      public static List<SAM_Quota__c> getTestRecord(){


         List<CustObject_XXX__c> listRec = [Select Id, Name, Year__c 
                                            from CustObject_XXX__c 
                                            where Id =: '0a2XXXXXXXXX'];

        return listRec;

     }
  }
```

Using Burp Suite Repeater module I am able to intercept the POST request for this field update and set in another value for the 'Year__c' and send it to successfully update. This is a CSRF issue. To fix it I have enabled 'Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection' settings under session Settings, Increased Lightning web security for LWC and pretty much all Web securities I can find inluding everything in the site

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_lightning_security.htm#Cross_Site_Request_Forgery .

Still the CSRF attack is successful. Is there any specific security practice or setting I might have missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't CSRF. Burp Repeater is software that intercepts network traffic at the device level. A compromised machine is required to make this attack feasible, such as a virus or browser extension being installed. CSRF occurs when a malicious script is somehow inserted into an app in order to do things on behalf of the user, such as stealing, modifying, or deleting data or credentials.

[Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-intro.html) has strict rules about what is allowed to run within Salesforce, so it generally isn't possible to perform a CSRF in Lightning through the majority of attack vectors a normal site might be vulnerable to. In other words, you're worrying over nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. But But why am I not able to update any field value from a normal Record page Layout? Getting an error 'CollisonDetectedException' which got me concerned in the first place

Comment: @Brav The standard Salesforce UI has collision detection to ensure that multiple users don't accidentally overwrite each other's saves. If you're not using the standard UI, it's indeed possible to overwrite data, because collision detection is technically opt-in (and has been since its inception).

Comment: Okay but I used Standard UI to update the field with a value,  then intercepted that POST request in Burp suite and used the Repeater on it to update to another value. Salesforce didn't allow this (But allowed for an update from an LWC).  I'm assuming this is expected but fail to understand how Salesforce differentiates both POST requests.

Comment: @Brav There's a header called `If-Unmodified-Since`. It's unclear if `lightning-record-edit-form` uses it, though. However, if you want a rendered UI but with conflict detection, you can definitely use `updateRecords` in an `onsubmit` handler to enable conflict detection.

Comment: Thanks! This will be enough security wise. I have implemented the same in my custom component. The collision detection will stop the value change. Now it behaves the same way when a record gets updated in the standard Salesforce page. On a separate note, I could change the modified date along with the value in Burp Repeater to successfully send a post request, in both custom and standard page requests (but I am not complaining )